# Custom view unnecessarily redrawn

Tags: android, redraw, custom-view

I have created a custom view **com.mydomain.android.KTab**, as the XML shown below, I have a **FrameLayout** on top and my custom view at the bottom.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/radialback">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentFrame" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#ffcccccc"/>

<view
    class="com.mydomain.android.KTab"
    android:id="@+id/kTab"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "80dip"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I programmatically add a **ScrollView** to the FrameLayout as in the following code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("a long long string...");
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
sv.addView(tv);
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.contentFrame);
fl.addView(sv);
```

Now it works good when seen from the surface, but the onDraw() method of my custom view(**KTab** in this case) is constantly called when I scroll **contentFrame**, I don't understand why my custom view is affected by the scrolling, it's unnecessary.

Anyone could give a clue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I have solved this problem.

It's quite a subtle problem, when I put the FrameLayout and my custom view in adjacent to each other, my custom view will be invalidated(and then onDraw() being called) when I scroll the ScrollView in the FrameLayout. I **guess** it is because the two views are next to each other and there's 1 pixel overlapped, when the ScrollView is scrolled and then invalidated, so will be my custom view.

The trick is to ensure that there's at least 1 pixel gap between the FrameLayout and my custom view, adding the following to FrameLayout properties saves my life.

> android:layout_marginBottom="1px"

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView is transparent by default (isOpaque() return false) and the view put inside the scroll view can be in any position (thus outside of screen) so that it can reveal your custom view which is beneath the scroll view... Therefore android cannot optimise away calling draw() on your custom view. You can mitigate it by subclassing ScrollView and overriding isOpaque() returning true (but then it might produce strange artifacts) or (better) put some fully opaque view between framelayout and ScrollView.

Comment: Jarek, you are awesome! I add an empty TextView in between the ScrollView and my custom view, now my custom view will not be redrawn when I scroll the contentFrame.

But I still don't understand why the transparency/opaqueness matter here.

Comment: Your'e welcome :. Since you are new to the site -> there are two ways at this site to express your gratitude... Upvote the answer and mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: Does it mean that when I add an empty TextView in between the ScrollView and my custom view, the TextView will be constantly redrawn when I scroll contentFrame? 

Adding an extra view to the layout solves the problem, but the extra view is not necessary from the UI perspective of my app, so do I have to resort to subclassing ScrollView? and if I do so, will there be any other things affected?

Comment: Now we are coming to the root of the problem. I think the main question here is why do you need to have invisible com.mydomain.android.KTab view at all? Is there a reason it has to be below the ScrollView? Should not you remove it before ScrollView is added? It seems that's what you want to achieve?

Comment: My custom view is actually another implementation of the TabHost API. What do you mean by invisible com.mydomain.android.KTab? both the ScrollView and my custom view are visible. and even if I explicitly set their android:visibility properties to "visible", the problem still exists. 

It looks like it is my custom view rather than ScrollView that causes the problem?

Comment: So you want to have your tab above and your scrollview below but both visible? I thought (my mistake - missed /> in framelayout) that both KTab and scrollview are in the same framelayout..... Then it is pretty  strange indeed and not sure why it's called like that...

Comment: Hi, Jerek, please take a look at this picture, I have already implemented the UI effect, the upper part is the ScrollView, the bottom is my custom view. I need to resolve the redraw problem. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6518271/Pic/android_tab.jpg